# JavaScript date elements are shown for next day instead of the current day

Tags: javascript, list, date, datetime, sharepoint

[image]

I have a form that shows different time spots (08:30-09:00, 10:00-10:30, 11:30-12:00).
It takes these spots from a list.

The problem is that (sometimes) it shows the spots of the next day.

In the list, I don't have spots for the date 18.10.2020. But it shows the spots of the next day (19.10.2020).

This is what the console shows:

[image]

The ID 9370 is the following one:

[image]

As you can see, the date is 19.10.2020.

I think that the issue must be in the following JavaScript code:

```
function loadSpots(dateString,divPicker) {

    var curvalue = NWF$("#" + varLocation).find("input:checked").val();

    if (curvalue == "Ulm") {
        var query = "$filter=(Date le datetime'"+dateString+"T23:59:00Z') and (Date ge datetime'"+dateString+"T00:00:00Z') and (Standort ne 'Taufkirchen') and (Standort ne 'Friedrichshafen') &$orderby=Spot asc";
    } else if (curvalue == "Taufkirchen") {
        var query = "$filter=(Date le datetime'"+dateString+"T23:59:00Z') and (Date ge datetime'"+dateString+"T00:00:00Z') and (Standort eq 'Taufkirchen')&$orderby=Spot asc";
    } else if (curvalue == "Friedrichshafen"){
        var query = "$filter=(Date le datetime'"+dateString+"T23:59:00Z') and (Date ge datetime'"+dateString+"T00:00:00Z') and (Standort eq 'Friedrichshafen')&$orderby=Spot asc";
    } else {}



    NWF$.ajax({
        url: "/tools/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Win10RolloutSpots')/Items?" + query,
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        headers: requestHeaders,

        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert("error:" + thrownError + "\n" + xhr.status);
        },

        success: function (data) {
            console.log("dateString: " + dateString);
            console.log("Spot data: ",data);
            var outhtml = "<table><tr>";
            var n = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++) {
                n = n+1;
                outhtml += "<td>" + getButton(data.d.results[i]) + "</td>";

                if( n>=8) {
                    outhtml += "</tr><tr>";
                    n = 0;
                }
            }
            outhtml += "</tr></table>";

            NWF$("#"+divPicker).html(outhtml);
        }
    });

}
```

I'm not really that good with datetimes and query parameters.
Can someone have a look if there's something that sticks out that could be the issue?

Comment: What time zone are you using in SharePoint?

Comment: @Amos_MSFT (UTC+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rom etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be the problem about the time zone.SharePoint stores all its date/time fields in UTC time. So the time you see is not the same as the stored time.
[image]
[image]
[image]

The time you see has been converted according to the regional setting.

Answer (score 1):

It is a problem about timezone.
For example, you visit this web page in China, while the server and database are locate in Germany

The selection of date is 2020-Oct-18.
So server will query all the data in 2020-Oct-18, including the Data with value "2020-10-18T20:00:00Z"

When you output the result in table, you format the "2020-10-18T20:00:00Z" with your own timezone(China), which is actually 2020-Oct-19. It is Oct-19 in China.

Comment: But my timezone is UTC+01:00 and for other days (not weekends) it works